# Write complete content in DataGrid back to xml file after modifications WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF that I fill with an XML like this:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = Responsible.GetResponsibles();
```

The `GetResponsibles()` method reads an XML and returns a

```
ObservableCollection<Responsible>()
```

When the user clicks a button the following method executes:

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //write the dataGrid contents to disk
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("dat",new XElement("responsibles"), new XElement("parameters"), new XElement("tags")));
    var itemsSource = dataGrid.Items as IEnumerable;
    if (itemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                string[] cell = new string[4];
                int colPos = 0;
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.GetCellContent(row) is TextBlock)
                    {
                        TextBlock cellContent = column.GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                        cell[colPos++] = cellContent.Text;
                    } 
                }
                doc.Root.Element("responsibles").Add(new XElement("responsible", new XAttribute("key", cell[0])));
                //TODO write cell[1-3] to xml
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Save("testOutput.xml");
}
```

I assembled this together using answers from several other posts regarding the same subject. My problem is that it only saves the visible content and not the complete data in the `dataGrid`. I fail to understand why after searching for a solution for a considerable amount of time. What do I need to adapt to access all the data and not just the visible part please?

This is the XAML for the `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AlternationCount="2" Height="253" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColorKey}}"/>
    </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That is because you are recreating your data from bound visuals instead of picking it from the view model. Can you share the XAML for this DataGrid?

Comment: I added the xaml to the question

Comment: See answer since comment got a bit long.

Comment: You should look into MvvM. You would have your collection of responsibilities in your ViewModel with 2 way Binding assigned to the `DataGrid` ItemsSource. I see you are using names for `UI` element?  In WPF you would only use names for animations or hacked binding. Bear in mind that `Binding` will reflect the changes in your collection so you would only refer to the underlying collection and have access to **ALL** records.

Comment: I will. I know I have a lot to learn. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not show your item template. Are you sure this is the entire XAML?

Anyway, what I am getting at is you should not pick from dataGrid.Items but from ItemsSource. If your databinding is two-way, then ItemsSource will already have up to date data.

Even better, you can retain a reference to Responsible.GetResponsibles() and two-way data binding will keep it up to date. Though pay attention to when update triggers, DataGrid is notorious for not posting updates to source.

Edit: Your imperative code makes me think your view model is not correctly/completely defined.

Comment: keeping the reference to the Responsible.GetResponsibles() solved it for me. I can access the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this: var itemsSource = dataGrid.Items as IEnumerable - You have all the content of the DataGrid. If the user has edited or added something in the DataGrid, the new data will be there too. 
In the foreach (var item in itemsSource) you can work with the item, which is of type Responsible, and just save everything you need from the item and just remove all the code related to the DataGridRow.

```
foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
      doc.Root.Element("responsibles").Add(new XElement("responsible", new XAttribute("key", item.PropertyName)));   
    }
```